# Coproduct in the category of $\Omega$-algebras

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, universal-algebra

Let $\Omega$ be a type (or signature, depending on your terminology), and let $\mathbf {\Omega Alg}$ be the category of $\Omega$-algebras. What is the coproduct in this category?

G. Bergman's "An invitation to general algebra and universal constructions" hints at this, but (unless I am overlooking something, it's a big book) doesn't provide an explicit construction for it. Where can I find an explicit construction of it? It should be noncommutative, nonassociative, etc. etc.

Comment: Take the free $\Omega$-algebra generated by the disjoint union of the two summands and quotient out by the appropriate congruence.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks.